# Scaling and printing PyQt

Tags: python, printing, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm attempting to print to paper a main window along with its widgets. Ideally it should fit the page. 
I've attempted the following code but to no avail! Any body know how to?

```
def printViewCustomer(self):
    printer=QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()
    dialog=QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog(printer,self)
    if (dialog.exec_()!=QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted):
        return
    printWidget=self.mainViewWidget
    painter=QtGui.QPainter(printer)
    painter.begin(printer)
    print(printer.paperRect().x())
    XScale=(printer.pageRect().width()/ (printWidget.width()))
    YScale=(printer.pageRect().height()/(printWidget.height()))
    Scale=(min(XScale,YScale))
    painter.translate((printer.paperRect().x()) + (printer.pageRect().width()/2),(printer.paperRect().y) + (printer.pageRect().height()/2))
    painter.scale(Scale,Scale)
    painter.translate(-1*printWidget.width()/2,-1*printWidget.height()/2)
    printWidget.render(painter)
    painter.end()
```

it was a attempted translation of this

```
QPainter painter;
        painter.begin(&printer);
        double xscale = printer.pageRect().width()/double(myWidget->width());
        double yscale = printer.pageRect().height()/double(myWidget->height());
        double scale = qMin(xscale, yscale);
        painter.translate(printer.paperRect().x() + printer.pageRect().width()/2,
                           printer.paperRect().y() + printer.pageRect().height()/2);
        painter.scale(scale, scale);
        painter.translate(-width()/2, -height()/2);

        myWidget->render(&painter);
```

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "to no avail?" Where is it failing?

Comment: @ChristopherPeterson Hi this is the error I get, I suspect its cause I don't have a clue with C++ and tried to translate the above but got it wrong! 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
     painter.translate((printer.paperRect().x()) + (printer.pageRect().width()/2),(printer.paperRect().y) + (printer.pageRect().height()/2))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float' `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's think about the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'
```

Before we do anything, just read it. *"unsupported operand types for +"*. Well, that sounds like Python is trying to add two things and one of them can't be added. Read a little more, and *'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'*. It sounds like you're trying to add a float to a method/function, which just doesn't make any sense.

So just to fix the error you're getting:

```
painter.translate((printer.paperRect().x()) + (printer.pageRect().width()/2),(printer.paperRect().y) + (printer.pageRect().height()/2))
```

should be

```
painter.translate((printer.paperRect().x()) + (printer.pageRect().width()/2), (printer.paperRect().y()) + (printer.pageRect().height()/2))
```

Notice that you forgot to *call* the function y, and instead tried to use the value of y which is a pointer to the function. You could be forgiven for forgetting that Qt uses methods to access variables like this. It would probably be more pythonic to allow access by [properties](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property), but this is how it is since PySide/PyQt wrap C++.

It was very clear what was wrong with your code once you posted the error - please try to remember to include that sort of thing in the future to save someone's time.

How does it go now?